# Query / design performance problem: How to get an Id via a 'link'-table in the most efficient way?

Tags: sql, performance, optimization

See this part from my ERD:

[Part from the design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gC7S.jpg)

From a reader, I get a RFID which belongs to a wheel. How can I obtain the corresponding Id from the tblProduct-table. I know how to do it with a number of SELECT-statements, but is this the fastest way? I am asking this because I do not have a lot of experience generating speed-efficient QUERY Statements.

On the moment I did create a function to handle this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].ufnGetProductIdFromRFID
    (@StationRFID NVARCHAR(20))
RETURNS
    INT
AS 

BEGIN
    DECLARE @ProductId INT = 0
    DECLARE @WheelId INT = 0

    SELECT @WheelId = [Id] FROM [dbo].[tblWheel] WHERE RFID = @StationRFID
    SELECT @ProductId = [ProductId] FROM [dbo].[tblLinkWheelProduct] WHERE WheelId = @WheelId

    RETURN @ProductId
END
GO
```

So i execute two query's.

My question: will a 'JOIN' or some other contruction lead to a more efficient (less executing time) solution? Since the two SELECT-statements are fairly simple and not time-consuming at all I think.....

Thanks already for thinking along with me!

Comment: I'd consider a `JOIN`.

Comment: can you tell us what you have tried so for so that it will be easy to understand the problem as well as for suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this way you can get whatever information from `tblProduct` table

```
select * from tblProduct p
where exists (
   select 1 from tblLinkWheelProduct lwp
   inner join tblWheel w
     on w.Id = lwp.WheelId
   where p.Id = lwp.ProductId and RFID = ?
)
```

if your intention is to only get `productId` then,

```
select productId from tblLinkWheelProduct lwp
where exists (
   select 1 from tblWheel w 
   where w.id = lwp.WheelId 
     and w.RFID = ?
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, nice work! But I think I have to measure the difference in executing times to get clear which solution is faster...

Comment: the second one is definitely faster since it does not have 3rd join.

Answer (score 0):

I would join tblWheel to tblLinkWhelProduct to tblProduct. You would get the data with one query. I think it is the best way:

```
select p.Id from tblWheel w
inner join tblLinkWheelProduct l on w.Id=t.WheelId
inner join tblProduct p on p.Id=l.ProductId
```